# Хостинг Flask app на локальной машине

Tags: python, flask, hosting

Интересуют вопросы хостинга на локальном компьютере. Есть приложение на Flask. Исходя с этого есть ряд вопросов:

- как заменить host(ip):port на имя сайта
- надо ли где то покупать это имя
- есть ли какое либо внятное описание/статья/туториал на эту тему.

Comment: Есть ли у машины публичный IP? Если нет, то сервис вроде https://ngrok.com/ нужен. Есть ли причины не использовать [бесплатный PaaS вместо локальной машины](https://github.com/ripienaar/free-for-dev/blob/master/README.md#paas)?

Comment: Статического нет. Касаемо PaaS ,  я так понимаю что там свои заморочки(Смогу ли я там задать свое доменное имя... в том же gae ?).

Comment: Если вы боитесь PaaS использовать, то самостоятельно администрировать относительно сложнее и поэтому для вас ещё менее желаемо (если нет образовательной цели, а просто сервис поднять хочется). Что можно и нельзя зависит от конкретного выбранного сервиса.

Comment: Допустим я разместил приложение на Azure. Как я могу изменить доменное имя ?

Comment: вбейте в гугл: azure custom domain name. Если что-то не ясно, то задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос, специально об этом (какие шаги выполняли, что ожидали получить, что вместо этого получили подробно, шаг за шагом опишите).